# Instantiate and Inject into AngularJS Controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I want to use a base AngularJS controller for multiple very similar views, but I want to change the `Resource` that is passed into each controller.

Here is the base controller:

```
coreAppControllers.controller('ModalEditCtrl',
    function ($scope, $stateParams, Resource, $state, $modalInstance) {
         // A bunch of methods calling Resource
    }
);
```

Now I want to use this controller in another controller, but using a `Resource` specific to the parent controller.

```
coreAppControllers.controller('MachinesEditCtrl', ['$modal',
    function ($modal) {

        $modal.open({
            backdrop:    'static',
            keyboard:    false,
            templateUrl: '/partials/v1/resources/machines/edit',
            controller:  //ModalEditCtrl with specific Machine resource injected
        });
    }]
);
```

This is possibly the wrong way to go about this in JavaScript.  In other languages I would extend a base class, but I'm not certain what that would be in a prototypical language.

---

## SOLUTION

Thank you to PSL for the answer, however that method failed to inject the `$modalInstance` correctly.  The eventual solution was to use the resolve attribute, and let DI worry about the rest.

*For some reason you must wrap the service in an anonymous function when passing into resolve.*

```
coreAppControllers.controller('MachinesEditCtrl', ['$modal', 'MachinesAPI',
    function ($modal, MachinesAPI) {
        $modal.open({
            backdrop:    'static',
            keyboard:    false,
            templateUrl: '/partials/v1/resources/machines/edit',
            controller:  'ModalEditCtrl',
            resolve:     {
                Resource: function () {
                    return MachinesAPI;
                }
            }
        });
    }
]);
```

Comment: If you want to change only the resource you could just do it do with Dep injection argument.  Ex: `coreAppControllers.controller('ModalEditCtrl1',['$scope', '$stateParams', 'DiffResource', '$state', '$modalInstance', ctor]);`

Comment: Another way you can use `$controller` option http://plnkr.co/edit/E0xCJO?p=preview

Comment: If you're calling the controller through your router, you could look at using the `resolve` property in the router itself: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17716871/how-to-reuse-a-controller-in-angularjs-with-different-variables-based-on-route

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your concern is more on the DI side, you could easily do it this way:-

Say this is your controller:-

```
function ModalEditCtrl($scope, $stateParams, Resource, $state, $modalInstance) {
     // A bunch of methods calling Resource
}
app.controller('ModalEditCtrl',['$scope', '$stateParams', 'Resource', '$state', $modalInstance, ModalEditCtrl]);
```

Just register your specific controller as well:-

```
app.controller('ModalEditCtrlParent1',['$scope', '$stateParams', 'OtherResource', '$state', $modalInstance, ModalEditCtrl]);

app.controller('ModalEditCtrlParent2',['$scope', '$stateParams', 'SomeOtherResource', '$state', $modalInstance, ModalEditCtrl]);
```

and in your modal just do:-

```
   $modal.open({
        backdrop:    'static',
        keyboard:    false,
        templateUrl: '/partials/v1/resources/machines/edit',
        controller:  'ModalEditCtrlParent1'
    });
```

This way you keep your controller follow [OCP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open/closed_principle) and any new view you just have to add a new one instead of modifying the existing one.

Here is another way you could do it using `$controller` service to get the instance of a controller based on the Dependencies that you provide:-

```
coreAppControllers.controller('MachinesEditCtrl', ['$modal', 'Resource2' function ($modal, Resource) {
        var viewModel = $scope.$new(true);
        $modal.open({
            backdrop:    'static',
            keyboard:    false,
            scope: viewModel,
            templateUrl: '/partials/v1/resources/machines/edit',
            controller: function(){
                 return $controller('ModalEditCtrl', {$scope:viewModel, Resource:Resource});
            } 
        });
    }]
);
```

**[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/Ozlc0x?p=preview)**

And well you can use any [syntactic sugar for prototypical inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/892595/javascript-prototypal-inheritance) (I use [typescript so i generally do *extends*](http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/extending-classes-and-interfaces-using-typescript)), but it depends upon what are you trying to extend? is the scope ($scope) or the controller (controller As) itself (You basically are going to extend the view model).